telegram bot and receive bot message
I have a question about Telegram bot, I created a bot and sent some messages through sendMessage,but I couldn't receive them through getmessage,only the messages I sent myself.
What can I do to receive the messages I want，thans guys.

getUpdates is used to receive incoming updates.
This does not include messages send by the Bot itself.
There is currently no API route to retrieve the messages the Bot has send, you'll need to keep track of that while calling sendMessage.

All right,thanks.
I just want to realize an automatic tracking weather forecast function. ios requests Telegram‘s sendMessage through shortcut, and the server updates the position information in the task after getting the location through Telegram‘s getMessage. Unfortunately, shortcut can't send information directly.
